# Get all data from facebook page to android aplication

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new in android programming and we have a small project at collage to do. I am looking everywhere how to get from one Facebook page the INFO data(https://www.facebook.com/vanillazmusic/info?tab=page_info) to my program, and then get that data to variables, so i can work with them. I installed and prepared Facebook sdk and everything, but now I dont have any idea how to do that. Any help or links  to you-tube or something would be great.

Comment: maybe a little investigation could help.... https://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `app_data` to transfer data to your tab, and it will be in the `signed_request` parameter. See the Facebook docs for more information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request